# WSO2 Identity Server will not work in HTTP mode

Tags: spring-boot, http, https, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to run a WSO2 Identity Server in my stack for identity management. Since this stack is deployed in a private network, and it is for development purposes only, I'm trying to turn off HTTPS traffic and have only HTTP traffic. In the future this stack will be deployed in a kubernetes cluster, where again I don't want to have HTTPS traffic between the components, but rather at ingress.

So the question is, how do I configure WSO2 IS to work with HTTP traffic only? I'm running version 5.11.0.

**First problem**: I try to enter the admin console `http://some-host:9763/carbon/admin`, I end up in `https://some-host:9443/carbon/admin`

I tried to edit `${CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf/carbon.xml`:

- I uncommented the `<EnableHTTPAdminCOnsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>` but no luck
- I also uncommented the `<HttpAdminServices>*</HttpAdminServices>` but this didn't help either, I still end up in the https version

**Second problem:** I have a java backend with some microservices and an Angular frontend. I use the `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` to route the traffic, also this component validates the bearer token. This exchange doesn't work either on HTTP, I always get redirected to HTTPS. Also, there are some microservices that pull data from the WSO2 IS instance, like roles, etc, and that traffic is also not working over HTTP, just HTTPS. I tried to edit the `${CARBON_HOME}/repository/resources/conf/default.json` looking for flags that might affect HTTPS redirection, but no luck so far

The documentation is not clear either on this. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I added the following to the `deployment.toml`:

```
[transport]
https.enabled = false
```

but it only results in the following logs:

```
INFO {org.wso2.identity.apps.common.internal.AppsCommonServiceComponent} - My Account URL : https://<some-host>:-1/myaccount
INFO {org.wso2.identity.apps.common.internal.AppsCommonServiceComponent} - Console URL : https://<some-host>:-1/console
```

and the admin console is available only on port 9763, but when I log in with valid admin credentials, it redirects me to the admin login page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the below config to the deployment.toml file and restart the server and check

[transport]

https.enabled=false

Comment: please see my edits in the question. Your suggestion doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. First make this as true (as you did)

```
<EnableHTTPAdminCOnsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>
```

2. go to `${CARBON_HOME} /repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml`
   and find the following lines.

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Make the settings `false` from `true`. Then you will be fine.